# Angular Apollo V3 - Jest error: Cannot find module 'apollo-angular'

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, apollo-angular, mjs

I recently updated angular apollo from 2.6.0 to the v3.0.0 and this update broke my tests.

I am using jest for my unit tests, while the app compiles and runs fine, my tests are unable to import any dependency from 'apollo-angular', and I get errors like this:

```sh
  Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'apollo-angular' from 'src/graphql/generated/graphql.ts'

    Require stack:
      src/graphql/generated/graphql.ts
      src/app/pages/test/test.component.ts
      src/app/pages/test/test.component.spec.ts

      1 | /* eslint-disable */
    > 2 | import { gql } from 'apollo-angular';
        | ^
      3 | import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
      4 | import * as Apollo from 'apollo-angular';
      5 | export type Maybe<T> = T | null;

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/graphql/generated/graphql.ts:2:1)
```

There is an order on [the module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules) and because 'apollo-angular' v3 is using `.mjs` the resolved file will be `package.json` (in `node_modules/apollo-angular/package.json`), the [package.json](https://github.com/kamilkisiela/apollo-angular/blob/master/packages/apollo-angular/package.json#L15) containing the 'module' property

```json
{
  "module": "build/fesm2020/ngApollo.mjs",
}
```

In short, when importing `import * as Apollo from 'apollo-angular'` I expect jest to resolve `node_modules/apollo-angular/package.json` which one will point to `build/fesm2020/ngApollo.mjs` which is the expected file to import.

Again, TS is compiling the project properly and is able to import this es module but jest it not. What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I was using an old version of `jest-preset-angular`

```
"jest-preset-angular": "^9.0.7",
```

I updated to

```
"jest-preset-angular": "^11.1.1",
```

I then had a minor breaking change that I fixed removing the `import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';` line from my `setup-jest.ts` file and the bug is gone.